# ASP.NET MVC Routing - Redirect to Route when Action Name and Url is same

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I need to redirect on different action based on role. I have made following changes to RouteConfig.cs.

RouteConfig.cs

```
          routes.MapRoute(
            name: "borrower",
            url: "borrower",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Borrower" });

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "broker",
            url: "broker",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Broker" });                

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Here is my controller

HomeController.cs

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if (UserPrincipal.Current.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            if (UserPrincipal.Current.IsInRole("Broker"))
            {
                return RedirectToRoute("broker");                    
            }
            else if (UserPrincipal.Current.IsInRole("Borrower"))
            {
                return RedirectToRoute("borrower");
            }                
        }
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Broker()
    {
        return View(); 
    }
    public ActionResult Borrower()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Code flow is working properly till `return RedirectToRoute("")`but after this code flow never goes to related/appropriate action and empty view is returned.

**NOTE:** Both Broker and Borrower views are not empty they have static text.

In network tab you can see proper redirect is being performed and URL in browser is being set to route URL.

[image]

`RedirectToRoute("Broker")` result in `302` response and user is redirected to `abc.com/broker` as it should but `abc.com/broker` does not hit `Broker` action method in `HomeController` and empty view is returned. According to `RouteConfig.cs` it should hit `Broker` action method.

Please point out what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: So your current url (from the redirect) is `Home/Broker` ? What is the problem you are having then ?

Comment: @Shyju Url on redirect becomes abc.com/Broker. But it does not return corresponding view instead it returns empty view.

Comment: When you access the url in a browser, you are view is empty ? So it has nothing to do with your Redirect. rite ?

Comment: @Shyju Yes, `RedirectToRoute("Broker")` result in `302` response and user is redirected to `abc.com/broker` as it should but `abc.com/broker` does not hit `Broker` action method in `HomeController` and empty view is returned. According to `RouteConfig.cs` it should hit `Broker` action method.

Comment: Who/What is returning the empty view then ? Put a breakpoint in your Broker action method and confirm whether it is really not hitting the action method. There could be other reasons for the view to be empty.

Comment: @Shyju I have already debugged this and I can confirm that it's not hitting Broker action method.

Comment: I just copied and pasted your route definitions and tried it in a local project. It works fine for me :)

Comment: @Shyju Let me isolate this in test project and will let you know my findings :)

Comment: It's working fine in isolation. Don't know whats causing issue in other application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I had a directory named "Borker" and "Borrower" at root of the web project. Due to this MVC routing module was being ignored and requests (`abc.com/broker` and `abc.com/borrower`) was moved to these directory. So I renamed these directories and everything worked as expected :)